# Same LIKE condition applied to many columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I have an SQL query that joins few tables and I want to filter records using same LIKE condition for many columns of result set. 
For example, I have columns t1.Name, t1.FullName, t1.Comment, t2.Name, t3.Description, etc in my query (t1, t2 and t3 are joined tables names) and I want to check whether t1.Name or t1.FullName or t1.Comment or t2.Name or t3.Description is LIKE '%sometext%'.
I'm just interested what SQL will be faster?

```
WHERE t1.FullName LIKE '%sometext%' OR t1.Comment LIKE '%sometext%' OR
      t2.Name LIKE '%sometext%' OR t3.Description  LIKE '%sometext%'
```

or

```
WHERE ISNULL(t1.Name,'') + '|' + ISNULL(t1.FullName,'') + '|' + ISNULL(t1.Comment,'') + '|' + ISNULL(t2.Name,'') + '|' + ISNULL(t3.Description,'') LIKE '%sometext%'
```

Or may be there is some even faster way?
I'm using MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

**UPD:** I've edited my second query to handle situations when some fields are NULL and when concatenation may contain pattern but fields separately don't.

Comment: Have you runned this in SSMS for an estimated execution plan?

Comment: can t1.name ever contain 'some' and t1.fullname 'text' ?

Comment: If one column ends 'some' and the next begins 'text', the concatenation option might return a match where the OR conditions would not.  Is that a problem?

Comment: if using concatination you should do it like
Coalesce(t1.Name +' ','') + Coalesce(t1.FullName + ' ','')

Comment: @podiluska Yes, I didn't think about that situation, but bummi suggested suitable solution for that. I'm just interested if it's faster to concatenate strings and use LIKE for concatenation or to use LIKE for each field separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep it written like this:

```
WHERE t1.FullName LIKE '%sometext%' OR t1.Comment LIKE '%sometext%' OR
      t2.Name LIKE '%sometext%' OR t3.Description  LIKE '%sometext%'
```

Several reasons for not using the latter, where **faster** doesn't even come into play:

1. [String summary statistics](http://madhuottapalam.blogspot.co.nz/2009/08/faq-what-is-string-summary-statistics.html) may be used to service the query, and it may combine different indexes on different columns under exceptional circumstances. This is not possible with the concatenated text
2. `t1.FullName + ....` may result in NULL - you have to handle this
3. `t1.FullName + ....` may result in Text being found between t1.Comment and t2.Name, e.g.

   - t1.Comment Welcome to the hub
   - t2.Name = Blenheim
   - sometext = 'hubble'
   - .. t1.Comment + t2.Name ... = ... **hubBle**nheim `matches` **hubble**

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do is to use **[`FULL-TEXT SEARCH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)**.

using `WHERE t1.FullName LIKE '%sometext%'` for example, stops the server from using index on that column.

Comment: Thanks. But what about query with joined tables? Can I create full-text index for columns from different tables?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of and number of columns and the frequency of the search string. And probably other things.

Note that the two queries will *not* produce the same results. The concatinating query doesn't handle NULL values the same way as the first one.

Imagine also the name ending with '%some' and the description beginning with 'text%'.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the second way is better:

```
WHERE t1.Name + t1.FullName + t1.Comment + t2.Name + t3.Description LIKE '%sometext%'
```

However both queries have advantages and disadvantages; query #1 can work faster if these fields contain very large (long) data.

Answer (score 0):

```
"WHERE t1.FullName LIKE '%sometext%' OR t1.Comment LIKE '%sometext%' OR
      t2.Name LIKE '%sometext%' OR t3.Description  LIKE '%sometext%'"
or

"WHERE t1.Name + t1.FullName + t1.Comment + t2.Name + t3.Description LIKE '%sometext%'"

=============
Here Both are take same time bacause each condition is checked by separatly one by one.
No way to differnce in both condition.
```